# DPI settings not applying to Java Application Window

Tags: java, windows, font-size, dpi

I have a Java Application that is used on high DPI 30" monitors.  however the standard 96% font doesnt cut it from a usability perpective.

I have changed the DPI settings at a Windows OS level to 125%, however it is only applying to the Java apps window heading and not the text contained within the window.

Can anyone assist with a solution without a code level change in the Java application?

Comment: What UI framework is it? Swing?

Comment: If you don't want a "code level change", then does that mean you want to change a Windows setting?  If you want to change a Windows settings, perhaps you might try [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?